# passing int into android activities

Tags: android, android-activity

i pass int to next activity using this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);    
intent.putExtra("selectedType", i);    
startActivity(intent);
```

and then receive this in activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
int i = intent.getIntExtra("selectedType", 0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(i),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but when in this activity, it always display 0.

Comment: lot of correct answer is given..so please accept correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

You are creating a new intent instead of using the one passed to your ActivityB. So use

```
Intent intent  = getIntent();
```

instead;

Answer (score 1):

use this `int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("selectedType", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

try `getIntent().getExtras().getInt("selectedType")`

Answer (score 0):

Try now,

```
 int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("selectedType");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    intent.putExtra("selectedType",i);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And receiving..

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("selectedType")) {
        int message = getIntent().getIntExtra("selectedType");

        Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);    
intent.putExtra("selectedType", i);    
startActivity(intent);


Intent intent = new getIntent();
                    ^^^^^^^^^ 
int i = intent.getIntExtra("selectedType", 0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(i),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're creating a new intent and trying to get "selectedType" on it. But that intent has just been created, so it hasn't that value that you seek.

Try to getIntent() method to get your calling intent, which has your "selectedType" value...
Here's a snap:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
   int value = extras.getIntExtra("selectedType", 0);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(value), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> and then receive this in activity B
>
> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent();
> int i = intent.getIntExtra("selectedType", 0);
> ```

This is wrong. You are creating a new intent object. To get the intent object that was used to start  this activity use getIntent() method.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int i = intent.getIntExtra("seelctedType", 0);
```